# Qt Quick Controls 2 Splash Screen

Tags: android, c++, ios, qt, qtquickcontrols2

I am developing a mobile app using Qt Quick Controls 2, and would like to display a splash screen while the app is being initialised. Currently, this is what the user sees when the app is started:

1. A dark background with the name of the app as a header.
2. A blank, white background.
3. The application window.

In that order for an Android 6 Marshmallow smartphone. If I add the splash screen to the application window, perhaps in a stack view, and then transition to the actual contents when it is initialised, (1) and (2) would still remain, right? Is there any way to tell Qt to display the splash screen instead of (1) and (2), or at least instead of (1)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First in `_yourProject_/android/res/drawable` create a `splash.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#353535"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
         <bitmap android:src="@drawable/icon" android:gravity="center" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

That sets the splash screen background color and icon that will be centered on the screen.

Then in `/android/res/values` create a `theme.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Then in the android manifest file, on the line `<activity android:configChanges=` add `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` after the label settings, then scroll down to the `<!-- Splash screen -->` section and uncomment and modify the line:

```
<meta-data android:name="android.app.splash_screen_drawable" android:resource="@drawable/splash"/>
```

Replace the `#353535` color with whatever the color of your application window is set to for smooth transition. The image is optional.

I just tested that and it works. Perhaps someone else will be able to provide a solution for iOS.

Comment: This doesn't address the first two concerns though; for that I think you'd need Android-specific code. What would be more interesting is something like this, if it's possible in a native Android app with Qt: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/

Comment: @MrEricSir - yes, I misunderstood the question initially.

Comment: Sorry for disappearing. I only got a chance to look at this now. I'm using Qt (Quick Control 2), so I'm a little confused about how I would incorporate this. After building the project, I can see the android manifest file, but that's it, and it obviously gets overwritten each time.

Comment: @someguy - you are editing the wrong manifest. You need the one that is in your project folder, not the one that gets saved to the build folder on every build.

Comment: @ddriver: So all the relevant android files will be under the {project root}/android folder, but how do I get Qt to use these files? Edit: Oh okay, so they are automatically added by Qt Creator. I'm using nothing but a text editor and the command line. Will have a look at what Qt Creator does.

Comment: In Creator - Projects - Build Steps - Build Android APK there is a "Create Tempaltes" button, when you click it it will save the "default" android stuff to the project directory so you can make modifications. There might be a way to do it from the command prompt, but I have no idea about that, I use the IDE.

Comment: I created a project in Qt Creator, copied the android folder with the appropriate modifications, added the splash code from your answer and finally modified the .pro file to add the android file paths to `DISTFILES`. Works like you said. Thank you!

Comment: I used this,but in my application when i click on textEdit an indicator under the cursor appear that I can use that for moving the cursor .splash screen appears in background of this indicator ,.How solve this?

Comment: I think the right way is this https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/ but i can't use it in my application,and it don't work.but your answer works and have problem.thanks if you can help

Comment: @mohsen sounds like a bug. In that case the course of action would be to file a bug report.